# raspberrypi.local not accessible on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, hostname, mdns

I used to be able to access my Raspberry Pi on the network using raspberrypi.local (raspberrypi being the hostname of the Pi). The Pi is connected with a WLAN usb dongle to my Apple TimeCapsule I guess it's where the DNS is located to translate this to an IP. Or maybe it might be a problem with Multicast DNS (mDNS)? It works for my computer (computer-name.local) but no longer for the Pi. What could be wrong and how to troubleshoot? Is there any setting I can make on the Pi? The Pi is running Raspbian with newly updated packages.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution myself. Apparently you need this package to make it work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnss-mdns
```